# how to detect long press of volume button in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on application in which i want to provide facility to user to do specific thing when you long press up or down volume button no matter my app is background or foreground.

I also want to implement this functionality when phone screen off but in stack-overflow posts says you cant do that.

i have used `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast listener for volume button press detection and it work fine no matter your app is background but thing is that i want to detect Long press of these buttons.

how can i include this code into my broadcast so i can detect up or down button press for long time.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // Do something here...
       // Needed to track long presses
        Log.e("Main activity", "KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This is my broadcast receiver

```
 intentfliter  = new IntentFilter("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");
       mReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver()
                {   
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         Log.e("Main activity", "Volume button press");     
                }
                };
                getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentfliter); 
                 manager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(getCallingActivity());


     }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.example.androidsample;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;




public class VolumeButtonPressedBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public static boolean sIsReceived; // this is made true and false after each timer clock
    public static Timer sTimer=null;
    public static int i;
    final int MAX_ITERATION=15;
    public static boolean sIsAppWorkFinished=true;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
    {


        sIsReceived=true; // Make this true whenever isReceived called
        if(sTimer==null && sIsAppWorkFinished){
            sTimer=new Timer();
            sTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(sIsReceived){  // if its true it means user is still pressing the button
                        i++;
                    }else{ //in this case user must has released the button so we have to reset the timer
                        cancel(); 
                        sTimer.cancel();
                        sTimer.purge();
                        sTimer=null;
                        i=0;
                    }
                    if(i>=MAX_ITERATION){ // In this case we had successfully detected the long press event
                        cancel();
                        sTimer.cancel();
                        sTimer.purge();
                        sTimer=null;
                        i=0;
                        //it is called after 3 seconds
                    }

                    sIsReceived=false; //Make this false every time a timer iterates
                }
            }, 0, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android I had edited my code and made it simpler.I just used simple logic- Once a call is received in OnReceive I start a timer which checks at a iteration time (according to your wish).Each time a timer called I used a flag to track pressed state.In case user doesn't pressed the button I just released the timer.
but you must take care when you successfully detected event, you may use preferences for it as user may still press the button and the timer would again start in that case.