# How to Identify pressing the volume button for a specified time period in android

Tags: java, android, onkeydown

Using  this  android application I want to identify whether someone has  pressed the volume up button or volume down button for more than 2 seconds. This is what I have implemented so far.

**MainActivity.java file**

```
package com.example.hardwarebuttton2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN && event.getEventTime()>2000){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "volume down button pressed for 2 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    }

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP && event.getEventTime()>2000){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "volume up button pressed for 2 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


}
```

What this code does is without counting 2 seconds it gives the output , as soon an I press the volume up or down button. So , what is the problem with this code. If anyone can  tell me how to solve this issue I highly appreciate it.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22371161/3168859)

Answer (score 0):

event.getEventTime returns the time of the up or down, not the time since the last event.  What you want to do is store the event time when you see a down, and when you see an up subtract that stored value from the event time.  That gives you the elapsed time.  If the elapsed time is more than 2 seconds, then do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Thank you . Using  , long time= event.getEventTime(); I can identify the event start time. Then how can I identify event finish time.

Comment: THe event start time is when you see the key in onKeyDown.  The finish time is when you see it in onKeyUp.